# R Plotly: joint x- and y-axis zoom in the two interactive graphs stacked vertically

Tags: r, plotly, zooming

I would like to be able to zoom into two vertically stacked plotly graphs **at the same time**. The example code goes as follows:

```
library(plotly)
subplot(      
  plot_ly(iris, x = ~ Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, type="scatter", mode="markers"),
  plot_ly(iris, x = ~ Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, type="scatter", mode="markers"), 
  nrows = 2, shareX=TRUE, shareY=TRUE
)
```

The plots before zooming in:
[image]

And the same plots after zooming into a [4.5, 5] x-axis and [0, 0.5] y-axis rectangle in the top plot.
[image]

So now it is clear that the y-axis of the bottom graph is not affected by the zoom. And it intuitively makes sense, but in my real application I make sure that input data for the top and bottom graphs is on the same scale and within the same range.

Is the intended behaviour possible within R plotly or any other framework offering interactive graphs?